# How to setMinDate() for ExtendedCalendarView

Tags: android, widget, calendarview

I am using `ExtendedCalendarView`. How do I use the function `setMinDate()` on `ExtendedCalendarView`?

Comment: Can you clarify what min date you are referring, i dont see any column with that name in the ExtendedCalendarView

Comment: If you use CalendarView, you will get the option to limit the starting date to a date of your choice. That function is called - setMinDate(). I want to know how to achieve the same using ExtendedCalendarView

Answer (score 0):

ExtendedCalendarView is not an extension of CalendarView, hence not all the methods available in CalendarView will be available under ExtendedCalendarView. Looking at the document in this [link](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView), i see we can set only the below fields

```
Current database columns

id - database id of the event
event (Text) - name of the event
location (Text) - where the event is
description (Text) - information about the event
start (Integer) - when the event starts
end (Integer) - when the event ends
start_day (Integer) - julian start day
end_day (Integer) - julian end day
color (Integer) - the color of the event
```